# Surjective, open, and continuous map on a 2nd countable topological space

Tags: general-topology

Let me start off with some definitions:

> A map $F:M \to N$ is **open** if for any open subset $U\subset M, \ f(U) \subset N$ is open.
>
> A topological space $X$ is **2nd countable** if it has a countable basis for its topology.

I know that if $f:M \to N$ is continuous, open, surjective, and M is 2nd countable, then so is N (the proof is quite trivial).

I was wondering, however, if some conditions are not necessary. Here is what I have so far:

Surjective: This is needed. Example: $f: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{R}, \ f(x)=x$ (with the discrete topology on both sets). $f$ is continuous and open but the desired statement doesn't hold.

Continuous: This is needed. Example: $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^*, \ f(x)=x$ (with the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ and the discrete topology on $\mathbb{R}^*$).

Open: I need help with this. To me if there is a **surjective** continuous map $f: M \to N$, that means there are at least as many open sets in M as in N but I am not able to prove (or disprove).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any countable space $Y$ with uncountable weight. E.g. Some ultrafilter space etc. Take $X$ the same set in the discrete topology, and $ f$ the identity map. This is a continuous onto map on a second countable space to a non second countable space.